# jquery multiple ajax check for all done? (order not important)

Tags: ajax, jquery

Is there a neat way to make sure a bunch of ajax callbacks have all finished? They don't need to be executed in order, i just need all the data to be there.

one idea is to have them all increment a counter on completion and check if counter == countMax, but that seems ugly. Also, are there sync issues? (from simultaneous read/write to the counter)

Answer (score 8):

The [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) method is available for this, it only fires when the last of the current  ajax requests finishes.  Here's the full description:

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the `ajaxStop` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxStop()` method are executed at this time.

For example if you wanted to just run something, document is a good place to hook in:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  //all requests finished!, do something with all your new fancy data
});
```

Or you could display a message when this happens, like this:

```
$("#ajaxProgressDiv").ajaxStop(function() {
  //display for 2 seconds then fade out
  $(this).text("All done!").delay(2000).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [queue](http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
var msg= $("<div style='height:100px;width:200px; background:#000;color:#fff; line-height:100px;text-align:center;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;z-index:1000;margin-left:-100px; margin-top:-50px'>Ajax done! Click Me!</div>")
.click(function(){
$(msg).fadeOut(1000,function(){
   $(this).remove();
   });
})

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $('body').append(msg);
})
```

the point is attaching `ajaxStop()` event to document for global check. you might be more specific if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Also $.active will contain the current number of active AJAX requests, for anyone trying to use it with JSONP requests (like I was) you'll need enable it with this:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.global = true;
});
```

Keep in mind that you'll need a timeout on your JSONP request to catch failures.